# Micro deposit verfication failed ACSS DEBIT PADS (Candada)

Tags: stripe-payments

**Issue**: After I have confirmed the acss_debit payment, I was unable to verify micro-deposits. I was passing two micro amounts as described in the docs but an error occurred saying, "the micro amounts passed mismatched", I have tried to split my amount into two and passed the decimal, but I got a different error.

**Question**:**Stripepayments**: How can I pass micro-deposit amount in live environment, in other to verifyMicrodepositsForPayment.

Below is the screenshot of the error

```
 let money = grandTotal/2;
            money = Number(money.toString().split('.')[1]);
            const money1 = money - 1
            money = money + 1
         await stripe.verifyMicrodepositsForPayment(clientSecret{
            amounts: [money1, money]});
```

Comment: Did microdeposit verification succeed with your code in test mode using Stripe's test account numbers and microdeposit values?
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/acss-debit/accept-a-payment?platform=web#test-account-numbers

>I have tried to split my amount into two and passed the decimal

I'm not sure I follow this. The microdeposit values should be whole numbers, in cents (e.g. a 32 cent microdeposit should be passed as `32`).

Comment: It passed in test mode, however, in live mode it doesn't. if my amount is $100, what amount am I supposed to pass as the micro-deposit?.
Thanks for responding.

Comment: **I have tried to split my amount into two and passed the decimal I'm not sure I follow this**

 I mean, amount eg if the amount is $100 then I divided by two, if it has decimal then I am sending the decimal. How am I supposed to pass the decimal values?

Comment: I have updated the question with a code snipet

Comment: I have removed the screenshot

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding. If a customer does not automatically verify their bank account after you confirm the PaymentIntent, you'll need to wait for the customer to receive micro deposits from their bank (1-2 business days): https://stripe.com/docs/payments/acss-debit/accept-a-payment?platform=web#web-verify-with-microdeposits

You won't know the micro deposit amount until the customer receives them from their bank. There's no way for you to calculate these, either.

You should only use `verifyMicrodepositsForPayment` if you've opted to send custom email notifications.

Comment: I have opted to send customer emails. What about the option?, How do I verify still.

Comment: I am using verifyMicrodepositsForPayment to verify, but I got an error that the two micro amounts passed mismatch the amounts. I know that the micro amounts are in decimal eg [32, 45] when used, isn't it?. Say for instance I have the amount of $120, if I am to use a micro-deposit  to verify using the verifyMicrodepositsForPayment, how do I go about it?.. Please I need a guide on this.